# Sum between dates (lines)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following situation, I want to sum how much I've sold from 30 days ago. For the date 01/07/2020, my sum (the amount I've sold) has to be between 01/06 to 30/06.

My table

| ID | CREATED_AT | AMOUNT_CENTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9000 | 13/02/2022 | 100 |
| 9000 | 01/11/2021 | 200 |
| 9000 | 29/01/2022 | 300 |
| 9000 | 30/12/2021 | 400 |
| 9000 | 25/12/2021 | 500 |
| 9000 | 03/02/2022 | 600 |
| 9000 | 08/02/2022 | 700 |
| 9000 | 04/02/2022 | 800 |
| 9000 | 07/02/2022 | 900 |

How can I do that in SQL (select) I use SQL Management.

Comment: Hi - unfortunately this is not a code writing service, you need to show at least some attempt at solving this yourself and then ask a specific question about the SQL you’ve managed to write

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples to work with:

```sql
SELECT SUM([AMOUNT_CENTS]) AS [Total]

FROM [TableName]

WHERE [CREATED_AT] BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()-1
```

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [CREATED_AT] BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()-1 THEN [AMOUNT_CENTS] ELSE 0 END) AS [Total]

FROM [TableName]
```